# SpecFlow scenarios - covering different websites

Tags: specflow

At the moment my specification files are along the lines of:

```
Scenario Outline: Do stuff
    Given I am on the "<website>"
    And I have entered "red" into the search field
    When I do something
    Then something happens

Examples: 
| Description | website         |
| Domain1     | www.domain1.com | 
| Domain2     | www.domain2.com |
| Domain3     | www.domain3.com |
```

Which works ok, to a point but isn't very repeatable or extendable for other environments (e.g. dev, test, uat, rel, stg etc..).

What's best practice here?

- Get the site details from a database?
- Get the site details from
  config?
- Something else?

My end goal is to have a suite of repeatable acceptance tests, that can run on a box, which can be pointed to whichever combination of environments is needed at that time.

Answer (score 1):

I would put it in the app.config file, so you define which website to test for all your tests in one place.

You could combine this then with a config file transformation to get more flexibility.

One option to do is, to use the SpecFlow+Runner and the Targets- Feature (http://www.specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-Runner-Profiles/#Targets).
You could define for every website to test a target which contains a config-transformation to the appropriate url. This results that you have every tests for every target also in your test explorer.

Full Disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow+.